# I want to assign permissions for a user to see the EMP table

Tags: sql, oracle, ora-00942

Error says table does not exist. My question is why do I get the error?

```
SQL> GRANT SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE ON system.emp to chap7;
GRANT SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE ON system.emp to chap7
                                           *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-00942: table or view does not exist
```

The table does exist,

```
 SQL> select ename from emp;

 ENAME
 ----------
 KING
 BLAKE
 CLARK
 JONES
 MARTIN
 ALLEN
 TURNER
 JAMES
 WARD
 FORD
 SMITH

 ENAME
 ----------
 SCOTT
 ADAMS
 MILLER
 Stuttle

 15 rows selected.
```

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps the `EMP` table isn't owned by `SYSTEM`? Do:

```
SELECT owner FROM all_tables WHERE table_name = 'EMP'
```

Also, what user are you doing the `GRANT` and `SELECT` as?

Comment: In the canonical SQL*Plus demo scripts, EMP is owned by SCOTT.